# Trying to join two pandas dataframes but get "ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns."?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes: `seren1` and `bbox`. And I want to perform an inner join of them on column named `filepath`.

```
seren1[["filepath", "label"]].join(bbox[["filepath", "label"]], on="filepath", how="inner", lsuffix='_caller', rsuffix='_other')
```

gives the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-c001a7adc7cd> in <module>
----> 1 seren1[["filepath", "label"]].join(bbox[["filepath", "label"]], on="filepath", how="inner", lsuffix='_caller', rsuffix='_other')

/projects/community/py-data-science-stack/5.1.0/kp807/envs/fastai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in join(self, other, on, how, lsuffix, rsuffix, sort)
   6822         # For SparseDataFrame's benefit
   6823         return self._join_compat(other, on=on, how=how, lsuffix=lsuffix,
-> 6824                                  rsuffix=rsuffix, sort=sort)
   6825 
   6826     def _join_compat(self, other, on=None, how='left', lsuffix='', rsuffix='',

/projects/community/py-data-science-stack/5.1.0/kp807/envs/fastai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _join_compat(self, other, on, how, lsuffix, rsuffix, sort)
   6837             return merge(self, other, left_on=on, how=how,
   6838                          left_index=on is None, right_index=True,
-> 6839                          suffixes=(lsuffix, rsuffix), sort=sort)
   6840         else:
   6841             if on is not None:

/projects/community/py-data-science-stack/5.1.0/kp807/envs/fastai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
     45                          right_index=right_index, sort=sort, suffixes=suffixes,
     46                          copy=copy, indicator=indicator,
---> 47                          validate=validate)
     48     return op.get_result()
     49 

/projects/community/py-data-science-stack/5.1.0/kp807/envs/fastai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in __init__(self, left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, axis, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
    531         # validate the merge keys dtypes. We may need to coerce
    532         # to avoid incompat dtypes
--> 533         self._maybe_coerce_merge_keys()
    534 
    535         # If argument passed to validate,

/projects/community/py-data-science-stack/5.1.0/kp807/envs/fastai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in _maybe_coerce_merge_keys(self)
    978                       (inferred_right in string_types and
    979                        inferred_left not in string_types)):
--> 980                     raise ValueError(msg)
    981 
    982             # datetimelikes must match exactly

ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

But if I convert them to series join:

```
import numpy as np
pd.Series(np.intersect1d(seren1["filepath"].values,bbox["filepath"].values))
```

It works fine:

```
0        S1/B04/B04_R1/S1_B04_R1_PICT0006
1        S1/B04/B04_R1/S1_B04_R1_PICT0007
2        S1/B04/B04_R1/S1_B04_R1_PICT0008
3        S1/B04/B04_R1/S1_B04_R1_PICT0013
4        S1/B04/B04_R1/S1_B04_R1_PICT0039
5        S1/B04/B04_R1/S1_B04_R1_PICT0040
6        S1/B04/B04_R1/S1_B04_R1_PICT0041
7        S1/B05/B05_R1/S1_B05_R1_PICT0056
......
```

Type Checking:

```
seren1.dtypes

filepath     object
timestamp    object
label        object
dtype: object

bbox.dtypes

filepath    object
label       object
X            int64
Y            int64
W            int64
H            int64
dtype: object

all (seren1.filepath.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str)) )
True

all (bbox.filepath.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str)) )
True
```

What goes wrong?

Comment: Some sample data to recreate the error would helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get away with this error as follow:

Let suppose you are trying to join df2 to df1. 
For join function to work correctly, you will have to same column name 'Column' in both data frames and also have to set_index on that column 'Column' in the data frame to be joined. To get df2 joined to df1 at column 'Column' use,

df1.join(df2.set_index('Column'), on = 'Column')